# jQuery sliding menu error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing animated menu with **jQuery** (3 levels). I'm using efects `slideDown` and `slideUp`. Sometimes (but no always), when I open submenu of first main item, submenu of second main item won't work until I refresh the page. It works OK with efects `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`, but I want to use slide.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/mcCAx/

Comment: I see what you're talking about , i'll get an answer for you, somebody else commented , but it looks like they deleted it

Comment: Could not reproduce. Make sure when asking a question like this to detail your browser/version that you are using.

Comment: @donutdan4114 I tested it in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the styling on your `<ul class="SubStage">` element was being overridden. So, fight fire with fire by re-overwriting the styling in a callback. Your side menu shows up every time. :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    

    $('li.MainStage').hover(
    function()
        {
            $(this).find('ul.SubStage').slideDown('slow',function(){
                $(this).parent().find('ul.SubStage').css({overflow:"visible"});
            });
        },
    function()
        {
            $(this).find('ul.SubStage').stop().slideUp('slow');
        });

    $('li.SubStage').hover(
    function()
        {
            $(this).find('ul.Sub2Stage').slideDown('slow');
        },
    function()
        {
            $(this).find('ul.Sub2Stage').stop().slideUp('slow');
        });        
});​
```

[Check it out here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mcCAx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcCAx/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {    
        $('li.MainStage').hover(        function()
            {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).find('ul.SubStage').slideDown('slow');
            },        function()
            {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).find('ul.SubStage').slideUp('slow');
            });

        $('li.SubStage').hover(        function()
            {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).find('ul.Sub2Stage').slideDown('slow');
            },        function()
            {
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).find('ul.Sub2Stage').slideUp('slow');
            });        
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't stop the animations from queuing up when running the mouse over the tabs. To see what I mean, run your mouse across all 3 tabs in your jsFiddle and in his.

Comment: @Aust - frmo what I understood - the problem was, after the submenu becomes visible from hover , when you try to find another submenu for hover it won't work , once you viewed a submenu , the other submenus will not show untill page refreshes - this fixes that issue

Comment: True. But based on the OP's comment `It works OK with efects fadeIn and fadeOut, but I want to use slide.` it just seems like he is particular about his animations. If he doesn't care about that, then this works perfectly. I was just making sure you realized that. :)